# curl -d to ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, curl, asihttprequest

I'm trying to convert a curl call to ASIHTTPRequest and I've mostly succeeded, apart from not being able to send the message bit.

This is how it looks in **curl**:

```
curl -d "hello world" \
"http://api.pusherapp.com/apps/11776/channels/test_channel/events?"\
"name=my_event"
```

and this is how it looks as an **ASIHTTPRequest**:

```
NSString *url = @"http://api.pusherapp.com/apps/11776/channels/test_channel/events?name=my_event";

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request startSynchronous];
```

They both trigger the event, but the curl call sends "hello world" as a message, whereas the ASIHTTPRequest doesn't.

I've tried it adding it as a post variable, or a header, but with no success.
Any ideas on how I can convert the "-d message" thing to the other format?

Thank you,
Andre

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your message to the body of the request, e.g. by using this line of code:

```
[request appendPostData:[@"hello world" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: Hi Claus. Thanks for your help. I had tried that already. It doesn't come through :/